# Using Glide on Android, can I configure a global DiskCacheStrategy to be used for all requests as a default?

Tags: android, android-glide

With Glide, I can set a `diskCacheStrategy` when I load the image like so:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
    . ...
```

Is there any way to set a global default for this? So that all calls behave the same, e.g. always only caching the source?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?